# Get Array of Multiple Maximum Key vs Values from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as below :

```
$data = ['data' => [
     'tree1' => ['fruits' => 20],
     'tree2' => ['fruits' => 15],
     'tree3' => ['fruits' => 20],
     'tree4' => ['fruits' => 17]
]];
```

How can I get the array with maximum `fruits` value with key & value as below :

```
array(
    'tree1' => 20,
    'tree3' => 20,
)
```

Currently I am extracting this array with Custom Loops and `If Else` Statements.

Is there any or better way to extract such array using PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to compute the maximum `fruits` value (this can be done using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column) to extract the values) and then iterate over the array, pushing the key/fruits pair when the fruits is the maximum:

```php
$data = ['data' => [
     'tree1' => ['fruits' => 20],
     'tree2' => ['fruits' => 15],
     'tree3' => ['fruits' => 20],
     'tree4' => ['fruits' => 17]
]];

$max_fruit = max(array_column($data['data'], 'fruits'));

$output = array();
foreach ($data['data'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['fruits'] == $max_fruit) {
        $output[$key] = $max_fruit;
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [tree1] => 20
    [tree3] => 20
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/DfAVV)

For the case where `$data` has multiple sets of tree data with different keys, you need to iterate over each of those sets, first to generate the `$max_fruit` value ([`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is good for this), and then using a nested `foreach` to get the matching values:

```php
$data = ['data1' => [
     'tree1' => ['fruits' => 20],
     'tree2' => ['fruits' => 15],
     'tree3' => ['fruits' => 20],
     'tree4' => ['fruits' => 17]
],
'data2' => [
     'tree5' => ['fruits' => 20],
     'tree6' => ['fruits' => 11],
     'tree7' => ['fruits' => 13],
     'tree8' => ['fruits' => 17]
]];

$max_fruit = max(array_map(function ($d) { return max(array_column($d, 'fruits')); }, $data));

$output = array();
foreach ($data as $set) {
    foreach ($set as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['fruits'] == $max_fruit) {
            $output[$key] = $max_fruit;
        }
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

In this case the output is:

```
Array
(
    [tree1] => 20
    [tree3] => 20
    [tree5] => 20
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/7ldV7)

Comment: I have one more question, If instead of `data`, what if the structure would be like `array('data1' => array, 'data2' => array)` ?

Comment: So there are multiple `data` arrays within `$data` that all have trees in them? Are there any other values within the `$data` array?

Comment: Yes correct @Nick, for ex, I won't have something to put instead of XXXX : `max(array_column($data[ XXXX ], 'fruits')`

Comment: Normally I'd suggest another question but perhaps this is what you want? https://3v4l.org/7ldV7

Comment: yes exactly, this was what I want :) Should I put another question here or not ?

Comment: Nah, just take it as a freebie :)

Comment: Oh Cool !! Thanks a lot again @Nick, It worked like a charm

Comment: Cool. I've updated the answer so that anyone else who sees the question and doesn't read the comments will get both solutions.

Comment: The Discussion Group link was deleted by me : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227361/discussion-between-luffy-and-nick